# Distribute Dart framework outside of package directory as project template

Tags: frameworks, dart, dependencies, dart-pub

I'm trying to create a Dart backend framework that developers can download as a dependancy and have the basic folder structure, Dart files and such generated for them in their own project. From what I understand, downloading a dependancy package only places files inside the package directory/ies (although, I may be wrong).

To get around this, I believe Dart can be used like a Bash script, and can place files in the project directory automatically through running the package's bin files in the terminal (illustrated in the Running a script in a dependency https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-run.html).

Would this be the best way to achieve the desired result? Or is there an easier way to download a framework as a project template? (I'd also like to place similar scripts for generating controllers and such in the tools directory, and don't know if keeping this framework as a dependancy would be necessary after 'install').

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pub global activate some_package` to be able to use `pub global run some_package:some_script` or just `some_script` to allow to run a script contained in a Dart package without adding it to the dependencies.

I think this is the best way to distribute it.